# Changing fstab makes system read-only

Tags: mount, ssd, fstab, fsck, read-only

I've got a problem writing changes in /etc/fstab files which make system read-only.

I have two drives on my laptop - SSD and HDD. I read a lot opinions about SSD optimization, someone says that nowadays there is not necessary to worry about, but  I faced a problem trying to optimize SSD usage. Adding any optimizing options to partitions in fstab makes / read only after system restart.

Here is my *fstab* file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b6ebbe28-8654-4919-8094-5eee18954247 /               ext4    discard, noatime, errors=remount-ro 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A5F0-7D4E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=1e4e6052-c8ba-4548-8ffd-457a4bc460bf /home           ext4    discard, noatime, defaults 0 2
# /var was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=d1fa1a62-eca1-4e13-8bf6-f30300a01cab /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=69c38a83-596d-4ad1-ab87-599445c4e910 none            swap    sw              0       0

# moving temporary files from SSD to RAM
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults 0 0
#tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs defaults 0 0
#tmpfs /var/lock tmpfs defaults 0 0
#tmpfs /var/spool/postfix tmpfs defaults 0 0

UUID="ec529d46-81de-43e5-ad88-d50818f93421" /sghdd ext4 defaults 0 2

# mount MEDIA partition as sghdd folder
UUID="ec529d46-81de-43e5-ad88-d50818f93421" /sghdd ext4 defaults 0 2

# moving SSD/home folders to MEDIA
/sghdd/Downloads /home/ornichola/Downloads none bind 0 0
/sghdd/Public /home/ornichola/Public none bind 0 0
/sghdd/Videos /home/ornichola/Videos none bind 0 0
/sghdd/Pictures /home/ornichola/Pictures none bind 0 0
/sghdd/Music /home/ornichola/Music none bind 0 0
```

With adding any option (discard, noatime, relatime) to /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda4 problem occurs after system restart. All attempts to use aptitude are blocked according to read-only filesystem.

To avoid it I should boot from liveCD, mount my / partition and remove added options from fstab. After that I execute in liveCD system:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2 /
```

reboot to installed system, execute:

```
sudo fsck -n -f
```

and only after it I can use aptitude again.

The main purpose of changing fstab is to add discard, relatime, nodiratime (or noatime) options to SSD partions. Why system is going to read-only?

Output of *blkid*:

```
ornichola@silver:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="EFIBOOT" UUID="A5F0-7D4E" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="9a3525d1-9e84-4a06-84d2-2b96818ac1b8"
/dev/sda2: UUID="b6ebbe28-8654-4919-8094-5eee18954247" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a5cd0868-f118-40a5-9ffd-09282504722d"
/dev/sda3: UUID="69c38a83-596d-4ad1-ab87-599445c4e910" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="9199a9cb-9656-489f-83ef-4fe2800e6706"
/dev/sda4: UUID="1e4e6052-c8ba-4548-8ffd-457a4bc460bf" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4bf6d060-a7bf-491d-ae53-da80b13c838d"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="d1fa1a62-eca1-4e13-8bf6-f30300a01cab" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6c06b7b5-67dd-4b39-9f63-58c3876b9cfb"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="MEDIA" UUID="ec529d46-81de-43e5-ad88-d50818f93421" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="869b4d14-7a3b-4eb3-b784-e6fbe3db5514"
ornichola@silver:~$
```

and ouput of *fsck* while system is read-only and options added to fstab:

```
ornichola@silver:~$ sudo fsck -n -f
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
fsck: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 9 -- ignore
fsck: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 13 -- ignore
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Leaving filesystem unchanged.
/dev/sda1: 9 files, 870/130812 clusters
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Warning!  /dev/sdb1 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (4853291, counted=4853223).
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (1301362, counted=1301355).
Fix? no

/dev/sdb1: 9358/1310720 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 389589/5242880 blocks
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Warning!  /dev/sdb2 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
MEDIA: 16/59744256 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 3800856/238947328 blocks
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Warning!  /dev/sdb2 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
MEDIA: 16/59744256 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 3800856/238947328 blocks
ornichola@silver:~$
```

Comment: *(...) nowadays there is not necessary to worry about* Indeed. So, save yourself the trouble and do not change it.

Comment: `discard, noatime, errors=remount-ro` MUST BE `discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro`. No spaces. The list of `mount` options (see `man fstab`) is a `comma-separated` list that ends at the first blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/fstab`:

In `terminal`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Change this:

```
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b6ebbe28-8654-4919-8094-5eee18954247 /               ext4    discard, noatime, errors=remount-ro 0 1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=1e4e6052-c8ba-4548-8ffd-457a4bc460bf /home           ext4    discard, noatime, defaults 0 2
```

To this:

```
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b6ebbe28-8654-4919-8094-5eee18954247 /               ext4    discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=1e4e6052-c8ba-4548-8ffd-457a4bc460bf /home           ext4    discard,noatime,defaults 0 2
```

And, to properly `fsck` your system and repair errors...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /` # check /
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4` # check /home
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1` # check /var
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: @ornichola Thanks for the update! Did the fsck work ok for you?

Comment: Yes, I executed it, no errors were found.